# Trying to left float a left curly quote but having some issues

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to float a large left curly quote so that the blockquote sits just to the left of it. I'm having a couple of issues though.

1) The text in the p tag continues to wrap around the quote symbol even though I declare clear: right; on the blockquote. I have never understood how floats are supposed to work so can someone offer some suggestions on how to get this to work?

2) Disregarding the issue above, the text inside doesn't line up with the top of the quote symbol itself however when I apply margin-top to the blockquote, it doesn't move at all. Suggestions?

I know I could solve this by using a background image of a quote symbol on the blockquote but I would like to do this with text.

HTML:

```
<div class="quote_symbol">&ldquo;</div>

<blockquote>To be or not to be</blockquote>

<p>Some other text on the page below</p>
```

CSS:

```
.quote_symbol{font-size: 4.5em; float:left;}
blockquote{clear:right;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want the quote text to sit just to the right of the curly quote symbol. What about changing your markup to:

```
<blockquote>
     <div class="quote_symbol">&ldquo;</div>
     To be or not to be
</blockquote>

<p>Some other text on the page below</p>
```

And your CSS to:

```
blockquote              { position: relative; padding-left: 4.6em; }
blockquote.quote_symbol { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
                          font-size: 4.5em; }
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1), you should set `clear:right` on p rather than on blockquote.

Regarding 2), try using `padding-top:0` rather than `margin-top:0`.

Comment: clear:right on P? I don't want any content other than blockquote to wrap around quote_symbol. Everything after blockqoute should be on it's own line. Also, trying to change the padding to quote_symbol did not work. I tried on the blockquote as well, no result.

Comment: Yes. Sorry to say, you really don't understand how floats work. "Clear" on an element means just that: from _this_ element on, everything should be on its own line. Setting clear on blockquote makes no sense if you want to wrap it around the previous element, because clear is the exact opposite of wrap. You must set clear on the first element that you _don't_ want to wrap, in this case p.